# Why my function does not run continuously?

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

I'm trying to implement a serial reader based on [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/93bdfb92b3da76f2e49c959807fc5643bf0940c9/Samples/SerialArduino) example.

I tried to implement the main function to read from serial and print it in a textbox in main page. I have to read a barcode with 24 characters and two end line "\r\n" so I initialize my ReadBufferLength variable to 26 (I don't know if it is correct). The parameters for the connection are correct and the connection is established. I would like to run the Listen function continuously so I can recieve data in any moment I'm using the app, printing always the data recieved in the textbox.

My code for the mainpage.xaml.cs is:

```
namespace App1
{

  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {
    private CancellationTokenSource ReadCancellationTokenSource;
    private SerialDevice serialPort = null;
    DataReader dataReaderObject = null;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string qFilter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM3");
        DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(qFilter);

        if (devices.Any())
        {
            string deviceId = devices.First().Id;

            await OpenPort(deviceId);
        }

        ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        while (true)
        {
            await Listen();
        }
    }

    private async Task OpenPort(string deviceId)
    {
        serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            txtStatus.Text = "Serial port configured successfully";
        }
    }

    private async Task Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
                await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dataReaderObject != null)    
            {
                dataReaderObject.DetachStream();
                dataReaderObject = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 26;  

        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

        loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);  

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;   

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string strFromPort = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
            txtPortData.Text = strFromPort;
            txtStatus.Text = "Read at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
        }
    }

    private void CancelReadTask()
    {
        if (ReadCancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            if (!ReadCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ReadCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CancelReadTask();
        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            serialPort.Dispose();
        }
        serialPort = null;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the applicaiton, the Listen function is called just once and if I send something on the serial port I never recieve data. Probably I miss something in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution...

I used System.IO.Ports package with two different handlers and an object collector:

This goes in the SerialDevice class:

```
 private static ObservableCollection<string> ReadValues = null;

 public static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
     SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
     string indata = sp.ReadLine();
     ReadValues.Add(indata);
 }
```

and in the main page, I added this line to the page_loaded function:

```
mySerialDevice.GetList().CollectionChanged += NewFunctionHandler;
```

where GetList() is a function that returns the ReadValues variable. And the NewFunctionHandler is something like:

```
 public async void NewFunctionHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
 }
```

Hope this will be helpful for other people...